# kubectl service can not start properly

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to publish my application to kubernetes, but my kubernetes master is periodically crashes.

I am using ubuntu 22.04,

- docker installed and running
- containerd is running
- kubernetes installed (but not running correctly)
- swap is disabled

when I restart kubelet, and smoke tests with

```
 $kubectl get pods
```

for a while it correctly lists the current master node,

```
NAME         STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
dt-control   NotReady   control-plane   23m   v1.27.3
```

but after a while it refuses the connection, giving the following message:

```
The connection to the server 10.0.2.15:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I've trued to capture what is happening with

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

I got this:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
kube-system   coredns-5d78c9869d-6fd4r             0/1     Pending            0               5m30s
kube-system   coredns-5d78c9869d-bcw8x             0/1     Pending            0               5m30s
kube-system   etcd-dt-control                      1/1     Running            2 (3m9s ago)    6m36s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-dt-control            1/1     Running            5 (85s ago)     6m33s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-dt-control   1/1     Running            5 (2m55s ago)   6m36s
kube-system   kube-proxy-4kv2p                     0/1     Error              5 (91s ago)     5m30s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-dt-control            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (8s ago)      4m46s
```

a few seconds later I got this, (so the containers are all dying)

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
kube-system   coredns-5d78c9869d-6fd4r             0/1     Pending            0               5m39s
kube-system   coredns-5d78c9869d-bcw8x             0/1     Pending            0               5m39s
kube-system   etcd-dt-control                      1/1     Running            2 (3m18s ago)   6m45s
kube-system   kube-apiserver-dt-control            1/1     Running            5 (94s ago)     6m42s
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-dt-control   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (6s ago)      6m45s
kube-system   kube-proxy-4kv2p                     0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (10s ago)     5m39s
kube-system   kube-scheduler-dt-control            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7 (17s ago)     4m55s
```

the kubelet log is:

```
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="5a2ffc3d0959e5bdce9e35809fc2beb071ede7fc29033db2d4e7753b24df9e8f"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-scheduler\" with CrashLoopBackOf>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 kubelet.go:2760] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Net>
12969 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://10.0.2.15:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/nam>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:527] "Unable to update node status" err="update node status exceeds retry count"
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="1c32c884bda1274ed713f12129abedcf18133f0f8bcdf16609c7114497d41c2b"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-proxy\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \>
12969 event.go:289] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"etc>
12969 pod_container_deletor.go:80] "Container not found in pod's containers" containerID="385bf2cffe948be78d2ee391cb741cc9bca5182f5f9d>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="18b810055b1682eaba474c793f52981fe76f873c7211dc3bf558c547f49e45a4"
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-apiserver\" with CrashLoopBackOf>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="d1dfe0d8f0ea2220f5fb77b08e6c50fc65056a716e83cc9b01f034e37a7f4ac4"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-apiserver\" with CrashLoopBackOf>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="d1dfe0d8f0ea2220f5fb77b08e6c50fc65056a716e83cc9b01f034e37a7f4ac4"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-apiserver\" with CrashLoopBackOf>
12969 kubelet.go:2760] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Net>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="514842c5b2db086681bf175ef82527e66ddd7f450638fe5d59942fd7ac71e7e9"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-controller-manager\" with CrashL>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="bd46d542c3c10187a92dafd1156b9da65357cb818403c0a108043d1001731ccc"
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="d1dfe0d8f0ea2220f5fb77b08e6c50fc65056a716e83cc9b01f034e37a7f4ac4"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-apiserver\" with CrashLoopBackOf>
12969 event.go:289] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"etc>
12969 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://10.0.2.15:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/nam>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="5a2ffc3d0959e5bdce9e35809fc2beb071ede7fc29033db2d4e7753b24df9e8f"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-scheduler\" with CrashLoopBackOf>
12969 kubelet.go:2760] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Net>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:527] "Unable to update node status" err="update node status exceeds retry count"
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="d1dfe0d8f0ea2220f5fb77b08e6c50fc65056a716e83cc9b01f034e37a7f4ac4"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-apiserver\" with CrashLoopBackOf>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="1c32c884bda1274ed713f12129abedcf18133f0f8bcdf16609c7114497d41c2b"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-proxy\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \>
12969 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://10.0.2.15:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/nam>
12969 kubelet.go:2760] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Net>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 pod_container_deletor.go:80] "Container not found in pod's containers" containerID="b20fa7836f2bdcd3fa96a8e7164e651e3286b3efc1ca>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="bd46d542c3c10187a92dafd1156b9da65357cb818403c0a108043d1001731ccc"
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 event.go:289] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"etc>
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"etcd\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back->
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="2e1d7510a69d173f96ea570bf5a7f3f3d7207b497f2add173c7027b81d2ff3ad"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"etcd\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back->
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="514842c5b2db086681bf175ef82527e66ddd7f450638fe5d59942fd7ac71e7e9"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-controller-manager\" with CrashL>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="2e1d7510a69d173f96ea570bf5a7f3f3d7207b497f2add173c7027b81d2ff3ad"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"etcd\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back->
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 kubelet.go:2760] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Net>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:527] "Unable to update node status" err="update node status exceeds retry count"
12969 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://10.0.2.15:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/nam>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="5a2ffc3d0959e5bdce9e35809fc2beb071ede7fc29033db2d4e7753b24df9e8f"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-scheduler\" with CrashLoopBackOf>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="d1dfe0d8f0ea2220f5fb77b08e6c50fc65056a716e83cc9b01f034e37a7f4ac4"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-apiserver\" with CrashLoopBackOf>
12969 kubelet.go:2760] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Net>
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="2e1d7510a69d173f96ea570bf5a7f3f3d7207b497f2add173c7027b81d2ff3ad"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"etcd\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back->
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="1c32c884bda1274ed713f12129abedcf18133f0f8bcdf16609c7114497d41c2b"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-proxy\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \>
12969 event.go:289] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"etc>
12969 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://10.0.2.15:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/nam>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=e57618b07103e2626db638c92e47e0f0 pod="kube-system/kube-apiserver-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=def84d323aa509a6d505f9f6147213bc pod="kube-system/kube-controller-m>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=827a678ded8511bb5e6fb0b24c3b369f pod="kube-system/kube-scheduler-dt>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=4a469caa-9541-481e-ac23-5d43ac5070da pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-4k>
12969 status_manager.go:809] "Failed to get status for pod" podUID=5d7214f91bf3ed50aa3dffefcb6036d3 pod="kube-system/etcd-dt-control" >
12969 kubelet.go:2760] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Net>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:540] "Error updating node status, will retry" err="error getting node \"dt-control\": Get \"https://10.0.>
12969 kubelet_node_status.go:527] "Unable to update node status" err="update node status exceeds retry count"
12969 scope.go:115] "RemoveContainer" containerID="514842c5b2db086681bf175ef82527e66ddd7f450638fe5d59942fd7ac71e7e9"
12969 pod_workers.go:1294] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-controller-man
```

Comment: oh no, i had my cluster working until i updated (yesterday )ubuntu and packages now getting the same error.

Comment: can you telnet master on port 6443 ? this seems to be a newtork issue since im getting unbavle to connect....connection refused

Comment: It seems to be not a network issue. If it would be, then it would be impossible to connect for a short time, which is possible, then the containers die...

Comment: after a  few hours i ended up checking logs and seems to be because certificates need to be recreated. if you run this,  is the api cert valid? kubeadm certs check-expiration